# Probability of setting a new record

Tags: probability, integration

I need to determine the probability of setting a new record knowing that the times of the $8$ finalists are $U(9.53;9.6)$, and the record is $9.58$.
Thanks!

I know I have to use integration, but I don't know what formula to use...$$\int \frac {1}{b-a}  $$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an hint.
Assume that you have only one finalist. Then the probability that he will set a new record is
$$P(X<9.58) = \frac{9.58-9.53}{9.60-9.53} = \frac57$$
Now return to the case of eight finalists. Each of them can beat the record with probability $\frac57$ so the probability that at least one of them beats the record is
$$1-(1-\tfrac57)^8 \simeq 0.999955$$